# How to insert data from one table into another as PostgreSQL array?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following tables:

```sql
CREATE TABLE "User" (
    id integer DEFAULT nextval('"User_id_seq"'::regclass) PRIMARY KEY,
    name text NOT NULL DEFAULT ''::text,
    coinflips boolean[]
);
CREATE TABLE "User_coinflips_COPY" (
    "nodeId" integer,
    position integer,
    value boolean,
    id integer DEFAULT nextval('"User_coinflips_COPY_id_seq"'::regclass) PRIMARY KEY
);
```

I'm no looking for the SQL statement that grabs the `value` entry from each row in `User_coinflips` and inserts it *as an [array](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/arrays.html)* into the `coinflips` column on `User`.

Any help would be appreciated!

**Update**

Not sure if it's important but I just realized a minor mistake in my table definitions above, I replace `User_coinflips` with `User_coinflips_COPY` since that accurately describes my schema. Just for context, before it looked like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE "User_coinflips" (
    "nodeId" integer REFERENCES "User"(id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    position integer,
    value boolean NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT "User_coinflips_pkey" PRIMARY KEY ("nodeId", position)
);
```

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: you should really avoid those dreaded quoted identifiers. They are much more trouble than they are worth it. https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_upper_case_table_or_column_names

Comment: Ha thanks, wasn't aware of this convention indeed! (In this case I'm working with an auto-generated schema though, so I wasn't able to influence the column name).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for an UPDATE, rather then insert.

Use a derived table with the aggregated values to join against in the UPDATE statement:

```
update "User"
  set conflips = t.flips
from (
   select "nodeId", array_agg(value order by position) as flips
   from "User_coinflips"
   group by "nodeId"
) t
where t."nodeId" = "User"."nodeId";
```